# short Glitch in making android dynamic

Tags: android

I am sending a json request using params and the glitch is when I hardcode the user name and password , it works and when I set the variables it doesn't ?
What to write inplace of "ankur@gmail.com" & "123456"

```
    EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edituser);
            EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editpass);
            Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);
            final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            String temp = '\u0022' +username.getText().toString().trim()+'\u0022';
            String temp1 ='\u0022'+password.getText().toString().trim()+'\u0022';

.........


final HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("user_email","ankur@gmail.com");
    params.put("user_password","123456");
    Log.d("jsonobject", "jsonobjectResponse: "+params);

.........

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,new JSONObject(params),
                            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {   .........
```

logs

```
07-06 12:23:32.365 4701-4701/com.production.vy.triqsquad D/jsonobject: jsonobjectResponse: {user_password=, user_email=}
07-06 12:23:56.046 4701-4701/com.production.vy.triqsquad D/aaa: onErrorResponse: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-06 12:24:04.765 4701-4701/com.production.vy.triqsquad D/aaa: onErrorResponse: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-06 12:24:07.584 4701-4701/com.production.vy.triqsquad D/aaa: onErrorResponse: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

why the password is before username when I am writing username above password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edituser);
            EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editpass);
            Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);
            final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            String temp = '\u0022' +username.getText().toString().trim()+'\u0022';
            String temp1 ='\u0022'+password.getText().toString().trim()+'\u0022';

.........


final HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


.........

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
params.put("user_email","ankur@gmail.com");
        params.put("user_password","123456");
        Log.d("jsonobject", "jsonobjectResponse: "+params);
                        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,new JSONObject(params),
                                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {   .........
```

It's done

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.........

// remove the '\u0022'
String temp = username.getText().toString().trim();
String temp1 =password.getText().toString().trim();

.........


final HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("user_email", temp);
params.put("user_password", temp1);
Log.d("jsonobject", "jsonobjectResponse: "+params);
```

What I'm thinking is that you do not have to insert '\u0022' yourself. `JsonObjectRequest` will do it for you when it stringify.

Are you developing the server too? If so, you can also access your server to see what is your server receiving to better troubleshoot your current problem.

Others will provide better answers if you were to submit the logcat/console errors too.

Comment: hey can you give me reason over why the user_password is coming before user_email in request in logs

Comment: I'm no expert but i think `JSONObject` works like a stack (last in, first out) at least when it `toString()`. Try adding another variable in the hashmap and logcat it. The last `put()` should appear first. However, this should not matter as these values are accessed by the key and not index.

Comment: Anyways, does my answer work? Just curious.... Have not been android programming in quite a bit.

Comment: nope but got help from another source to put the params in the onclicklistener and that damn work.